# Multiple property-placeholder with overlapping locations does not work?

Tags: java, spring

I have three properties files:

**file1.properties contains:**
`propA=1`

**file2.properties contains:**
`propA=2
 propB=2`

**file3.properties contains:**
`propA=3
 propB=3
 propC=3`

And two application-context:

**applicationContext1.xml contains:** 
`<context:property-placeholder
            location="classpath:file1.properties,classpath:file2.properties"
            ignore-resource-not-found="true"
            ignore-unresolvable="true" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>`

**applicationContext2.xml contains:** 
`<context:property-placeholder
            location="classpath:file2.properties,classpath:file3.properties"
            ignore-resource-not-found="true"
            ignore-unresolvable="true" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>`

And a test that loads both contexts and injects all properties.
MyTest.java:

```
@Value("${propA}")
private String propA;

@Value("${propB}")
private String propB;

@Value("${propC}")
private String propC;
```

And i get the following values:

```
 propA=2
 propB=2
 propC=3
```

Why 'propA' and 'propB' wasn't taken from file3.properties?

Comment: Why should it. As soon as it is replaced it is replaced. If the first placeholder has done its job there is nothing left to replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having multiple property-placeholder-configurers does not work as you assumed. There is no property-override feature.  The first one tries and replaces what it can, then the next one takes its chance **with what is left** and so on. 
If you want to override properties you might better define a properties bean with multiple sources such as :

```
<bean name="appProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">  
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:conf/app-defaults.properties</value>
                <value>file:${CATALINA_BASE}/conf/my-app.properties</value>                 
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

The above code defines a properties bean with defaults, coming from a classpath file and an optional externalized file that overrides defaults and resides in a tomcat installation.
Then you can use a property placeholder like:

```
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="appProperties" />
```

Comment: Thanks, it appears you and M.Deinum are right. But how can i override/extend a behavior of property-placeholder defined in production applicationContext just for my tests?

Comment: Its not the behavior of the placeholder-configurer itself. I think you 'd rather express what actually want to do in more details in a new question with more details in configuration

Answer (score 0):

`Applicationcontext2` has override `applicationcontext1`.

To confirm add one new variable in `file1.prop` that should not available in another two file2 and file3.

Comment: I added new property to file1 and it was injected to the class, so applicationContext2 did not override applicationcontext1.